# custom vm deployment in azure

Tags: azure, deployment, virtual-machine

I am trying to deploy a vm in azure. I have two components : a boot file in .iso format and an os disk in vmdk format. We use iso file as an image and vmdk as the disk, while deploying it in a virtual box. Any idea if there is a way in Azure to use both the image and disk to spin up a vm?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The VM and VMDK files are only usable on a VMware ESX. Azure uses Hyper-V so will not read a VMware files. You need to convert it to the Hyper-V format and then upload and create the deployment. The same for ISO.

Regarding VMDK:

1) [Convert](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/07/14/step-by-step-migrating-from-vmware-to-microsoft-azure/). Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter link is not working there, but you may get that [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn873998%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

2) Prepare the virtual machine for uploading and importing. There is a [sequence of steps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/) that should be done before uploading.

3) Upload and import.

Regarding ISO - there are various ways to convert it, for example, [there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scicoria/2015/12/07/creating-a-vhd-from-iso-using-wim2vhd-convert-windowsimage/).

In the end of the day, you should upload your image as an VHD (using links above). Regarding VMDK - if everything that is that disk consists of is the data, then you may even do not need to convert/etc. After you upload and create the image, and create the VM from that, you will be able to attach the d[ata disk to that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/) - then just transfer your data to that, and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alex :) But the vmdk file is not purely a data disk. Although i will give it a try and get back.

Comment: Anyway, you will need to have VHD only :) so, i would start with differentiating the disks - to create the image only, and to create the disk with the data only. Hope everything will be OK :)